# The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component

Tags: react-native

I am creating an app using React Native but my code keeps giving this error "The  component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the  component or absolute positioning."

None of the Image components in the code in any of the files contain a child component and yet I am getting this error. Also, the error is not giving any trace so I'm stuck. Here's the link to the code, https://snack.expo.io/O3SFiTN9p, it's a snack link.

Helllllp!!!

Comment: I don't see any crashes or errors in the snack you provided.

Comment: Try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that may help you (and us) better understand the problem.